# Data allocation to pointers in C

Tags: c

```
char *p = "abc"; 
char *q = "abc"; 

if (p == q) 
printf ("equal"); 
else 
printf ("not equal");
```

Output:
equal

Is it compiler specific, or is it defined somewhere in the standards to be as expected behaviour.

Comment: What is the "expected behavior"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is permitted to 'coalesce' string literals, but is not required to.

From 6.4.5/6 String literals:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values.

In fact, the compiler could merge the following set of literals:

```
char* p = "abcdef";
char* q = "def";
```

such that `q` might point 'inside' the string pointed to by `p` (ie., `q == &p[3]`).

Comment: Sorry i am new to C. Where did you find the documentation pasted above?

Comment: @Jimm: from a PDF of the C99 standard. You can get a free copy here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf  See this SO answer for information about other standards: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents/83763#83763  Note that while it's a good document to have if you're serious about C, it's an absolutely terrible document to *learn* C from. Another book I'd suggest is Harbison & Steele's "C: A Reference Manual". It's not a tutorial either, but it's a great reference and is much more accessible than the standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing strings shouldnt you be using strcmp ?

Comment: @grossvogel - I realize that but I think the op is trying to compare strings.

Comment: if the OP is trying to compare strings, he wouldn't ask the question: `strcmp("abc", "abc")` should equal 0 and I doubt that that's what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 1):

It is not about some "data allocation to pointers". It is about whether each instance of string literal is guaranteed to be a different/distinct array object in C. The answer is no, they are not guaranteed to be distinct. The behavior in this case is implementation-dependent. You can get identical pointers in your example, or you can get different pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on it. This depends on an omptimization the compiler does to reduce the size of the binary.